# How to add "for submission" flag to Unreal Engine build when building project from command line?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

When creating package for Ps5 or XSX we can add additional flags that define builds as submission-ready.
If I understand correctly: for PS5 it is "--for_submission" and for XSX it is "/l".
But how to pass it to BuildGraph or BuildCookRun to have it packaged with those flags?

Setting GameConfigurations to shipping is not enough.